# AWS AppSync - Fatal error: Credentials Provider and endpoint not set

Tags: amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-sdk-ios

I have an iOS app that uses an AppSync GraphQL API created with AWS Amplify. I want some queries to be available with public auth (for unauthenticated users) via IAM. For this public case, when calling the API, I get the following error from `AWSAppSync/AWSAppSyncClient/AWSAppSyncHTTPNetworkTransport.swift`:

`Fatal error: Credentials Provider and endpoint not set`

The AppSync initialization is done in the AppDelegate:

```
let serviceConfigIAM = try AWSAppSyncServiceConfig(forKey: "bookapi_AWS_IAM")
let cacheConfigIAM = try AWSAppSyncCacheConfiguration(useClientDatabasePrefix: true, appSyncServiceConfig: serviceConfigIAM)
let clientConfigIAM = try AWSAppSyncClientConfiguration(appSyncServiceConfig: serviceConfigIAM, cacheConfiguration: cacheConfigIAM)
appSyncClient = try AWSAppSyncClient(appSyncConfig: clientConfigIAM)
```

I noticed in `AWSAppSyncClientConfiguration#makeNetworkTransportForIAM` that the resolvedCredentialsProvider is nil:

```
// Evaluates to nil
let resolvedCredentialsProvider = authProvider ?? AWSServiceInfo().cognitoCredentialsProvider
```

Do I need to create a credentials provider and pass it to the AppSync client config? How can I use IAM for unauthenticated users?